# How to populate Object with key: value in JS?

Tags: javascript

I have the following function. The current output is `name: "foo" surname: "bar"`

How can I push my console log data to my payload

```
{
  name: "foo",
  surname: "bar
}
```

so the output becomes:

```
const ProcessHTML = (rawHtml, elements) => {
  const $ = cheerio.load(rawHtml);
  let payload = {}

  for (const data in elements) {
    let currentElement = $(elements[data]);
    let prettify = pretty(currentElement.html())
    console.log(`${data}: ${prettify}`)
  }
  return payload
};
```

Comment: Sorry are you able to write an example. I read about it and still dont understand how to assign the key and value

Comment: [Don't use `for…in` enumerations on array-like objects like `elements`!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)

Comment: Just do `payload[data] = prettify` instead of just logging it?

Comment: @bergi thank you i was doing payload = { payload[data]: prettify }

Comment: Yeah, that's not the correct syntax. You *could* do `payload = {...payload, [data]: prettify}`, but that would be weird. Just assign to the property.

Answer (score -1):

I can't understand if you are trying to output a single value in console or the full payload object, but I think is something like that:

```
const ProcessHTML = (rawHtml, elements) => {
  const $ = cheerio.load(rawHtml);
  let payload = {}

  elements.forEach( data => {    
    let prettify = pretty($(elements[data]).html());
    payload = Object.assing(payload, { data:prettify });
    console.log(`${data}: ${prettify}`)
  })

  return payload
};
```

If you need to output the entirely object, just change the console.log to `console.log(payload)`